# Why do I have to use async with when using the aiohttp module?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

When writing asynchronous crawlers using `asyncio` and `aiohttp` in Python, I have always had a question: why you must use `async with`, and it's easy to report errors if you don't use them.

Although `aiohttp` also has a method `request`, it can support calling a simpler api. I want to know what is the difference. I still like the `requests` module very much, I don't know if it can be used as simple as the `requests` module.

Answer (score 5):

> why you must use `async with`

It's not like you **must** use `async with`, it's just a fail-safe device for ensuring that the resources get cleaned up. Taking a classic example from the [documentation](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#getting-started):

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()
```

You can re-write it as:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    response = await session.get(url)
    return await response.text()
```

This version appears to work the same, but it doesn't close the response object, so some OS resources (e.g. the underlying connection) may continue to be held indefinitely. A more correct version would look like this:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    response = await session.get(url)
    content = await response.text()
    response.close()
    return content
```

This version would still fail to close the response if an exception gets raised while reading the text. It could be fixed by using `finally` - which is exactly what `with` and `async with` do under the hood. With an `async with` block the code is more robust because the language makes sure that the cleanup code is invoked whenever execution leaves the block.

Comment: think you for your answer.  but i still have a question i want to know zhe async with why is important.

Comment: @hfldqwe The answer addresses that in the last paragraph. If some part is unclear, please be specific so I can improve it.

Comment: I am sorry to reply now, I have a place that I can't understand: I have emphasized in the documentation (and many other explanations) that I want to use async with, but it is not allowed to use it. And there is a problem with async with (that is, session is not close), I don't know if Python's object recycling mechanism can handle it. If I use aiohttp as a crawler in my project and use tornado to write the backend interface, then it seems that it is very difficult to write async with in Tornado's RequestHandler.

Comment: Usually I do this.
```
    Async def login(self, client, username, password'):
 。。。
        Async with client.post(url.login_url(), headers=url.headers, data=data) as resp:
            Result = await resp.json()
            # Determine whether the login is successful
            If result['success'] == True:
                Return resp.cookies
```
```
Async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=jar) as client:
     Cookies = await spider.login(client, username=username, password=password)
```

Comment: But in tornado I can't pass the client as a parameter to my crawler.
E.g:
```
Class InfoHandler(BaseHandler):
    ''' Return to personal information '''
    Async def get(self):
        Async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
            Result = await spider.login(client,username='xxx', password='xxx')
```
This creates a session for each link, which is a waste of resources, and is not recommended for use in aiohttp. How can I do this?

Comment: Does Markdown not support in the comments? I don't seem to know a little about the use of Stack Overflow. If there is anything wrong with it, please let me know, thank you very much.

Comment: @hfldqwe On StackOverflow, comments are not the place for code samples or extended discussions. You can use the "edit" link next to the question to clarify your question instead. In this case, I don't understand why you're "not allowed" to use `async with`. In other words, you need to very clearly explain the actual problem you are encountering with `async with` in particular.